# Core Data inputting numbers > 1.0 error

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsnumber

I'm working on coding a journal application which uses core data to store amongst other things, theme data (what the app looks like) - this was working until recently when I changed quite a lot of code. I'm now coming across an issue when trying to import a float into a managed object model if that float is > `1.0f`. When I also switch these same values to use ints they also fail to work if greater than 1.. Can anyone shed any light on whats going on?

Code:

```
    NSManagedObject *ocean = [NSEntityDescription
                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Colour"
                              inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [ocean setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f] forKey:@"barRed"];
    [ocean setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:101.0f] forKey:@"barGreen"];
    [ocean setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0f] forKey:@"barBlue"];
    [ocean setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:69.0f/255.0f] forKey:@"backgroundRed"];
    [ocean setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:69.0f/255.0f] forKey:@"backgroundGreen"];
    [ocean setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:69.0f/255.0f] forKey:@"backgroundBlue"];
    [ocean setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"selected"];
    [ocean setValue:@"Ocean Blue" forKey:@"themeName"];
```

It worked fine when I divided the colours by 255, and you can still see those lines in the code.. but I have decided to divide by 255 elsewhere so this new issue is a bit of a pain! The error produced when running the code is..

```
2015-05-30 12:32:59.381 Journal[3991:86301]   DetailedError: {
NSLocalizedDescription = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1610.)";
NSValidationErrorKey = barRed;
NSValidationErrorObject = "<Colour: 0x7f9af0f5aea0> (entity: Colour; id: 0x7f9af0f5af50 <x-coredata:///Colour/tAF642E65-FBB9-4589-A6C1-96C239E0E4DA2> ; data: {\n    backgroundBlue = \"0.2705882\";\n    backgroundGreen = \"0.2705882\";\n    backgroundRed = \"0.2705882\";\n    barBlue = 100;\n    barGreen = 101;\n    barRed = 3;\n    selected = 0;\n    themeName = \"Ocean Blue\";\n})";
NSValidationErrorValue = 3;
}
```

I've noticed the error code produced is 1610 - which is a [NSValidationNumberTooLargeError](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Validation_Error_Codes), which denotes some numerical value is too large. It produces this for the `barRed`,`barGreen` and `barBlue` values..

Any help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have a constraint in your Core Data model. Along with the data type, you can set default values as well as *minimum* and *maximum* values. I think you probably have it configured to be between 0 and 1. Update the validation rule in your model and all should be well.

The options can be found in the Data Model Inspector:

[image: Xcode Data Model Inspector]

Comment: Where would the validation rule be? I haven't sent something intentionally but it's quite possible I have accidentally done something!

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: You sir are a legend! I always have the side bar hidden - that will teach me!